# Why can't run S3FS on custom SM image as SM doesn't run docker image with privilege

Tags: docker, docker-compose, amazon-sagemaker, docker-image, s3fs

Are you using a Sagemaker custom image: yes

**Describe the problem**

I create a custom image to support training a large number of models on multiple instances. 
To do this, I choose S3FS to provisioning a share S3 location for all instances.

When running this docker image outside Sagemaker, I have to use either `--privileged` or `--cap-add SYS_ADMIN --device /dev/fuse` param on docker run to enable more privilege for the container. This is fine to make the image to run on multiple EC2 instance writing out models on that share location.

When moving that image to run on Sagemaker, by default, SM doesn't run the image with extras permission, hence, the S3FS failed on Sagegmaker as the SM doesn't provide a permission to provisioning /dev/fuse to load fuse module.

I don't know if there is away to enable SageMaker to run custom image with more priviledge?

Comment: Are you trying to use S3FS for training data?

Comment: @Ngenator Nope, data training has been sync as a part of SM Input. S3FS is used to sync model artifacts during the training as multiple processes on different instances needs to get updates when there is a change on the share s3.
A work around is to do manually sync back/forward model artifacts, but having S3FS would be seamlessly handling this behind the scene.